# how to send file to another user on same server avoiding password requirement of recipient?

Tags: file, passwords, transfer

I'm new to linux but have been experimenting some and figured it would be helpful to be able to transfer work files to my fellow students when we're working on a project. I've found a command that works, however, this requires me to know the password of the user I want to send the file to.

scp path/to/sourcefile user@hostname:path/to/destfile

This is the command I used, it prompts for the password of the recipient user. I do not know the passwords of my friends user accounts, so I am stuck. It seems advisable that there's no revealing of the passwords for security reasons, so that's why I am asking whether there's a way to avoid the password requirement or to simply send the file and the recipient is prompted with a message for agreement to accepting the file?

Thanks in advance.